# How rewrite C# code to python - compute SHA1

Tags: c#, python

I have C# code, which computes SHA1 and I want to know how to rewrite it to Python.
My Python code doesn't give the same output as C#

C#:

```cs
protected override string GetSign(string str)
{
    var UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    var MessageBytes = UE.GetBytes(str);
    var SHhash = new SHA1Managed();
    m_signature = SHhash.ComputeHash(MessageBytes);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m_signature);
}
```

Python:

```py
sha_1 = hashlib.sha1()
sha_1.update(tmp.encode('utf-8'))
result = sha_1.hexdigest()
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you specify exactly what output you expect?

Comment: in 2012 Sha1 became obsolete. 2013,2016 Ms and google have been advocating for people to stop using it.

Comment: `UnicodedEncoding` != `UTF8`. `UE.GetBytes("hello")` returns 10 bytes, `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello")` returns 5 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

like @xdtTransform said sha1 is obsolete. I assume your c# code is way too old. If you are refactoring it in python, it's better to go with SHA256 like below.

```
result = hashlib.sha256(tmp.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```